# How to check if an element is present in a Django queryset?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-models

Is it like a regular python set?

Suppose I have the following queryset

```
entry_set = Entry.objects.all()
```

How do I check if Entry Object e is present in entry_set?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
if e in Entry.objects.all():
        #do something
```

Or the best approach:

```
if Entry.objects.filter(id=e.id).exists():
        #do something
```

Comment: What if I have an Entry title instead of Entry object and want to check if that title exists in queryset?

Comment: @Brian, you could do something like `Entry.objects.filter(title='Your awesome title').exists()`

Answer (score 15):

The best approach, according to Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#exists

```
if Entry.objects.filter(id=item.id).exists():
    # Do something
```

But you can also do:

```
if item in Entry.objects.all():
    # Do something
```

Although this approach is the **worser** as possible. Because it will loop over the whole Queryset pulling elements from the database one by one, compared to the other approach that is almost everything done in the Database level.

If you have a list of ids or a Queryset others approaches would be use `__in`

Example with a Queryset:

```
query_ids = other_queryset.values_list('field_id', flat=True)
if Entry.objects.filter(id__in=query_ids).exists():
    # Do something
```

Or if you have a list of ids:

```
if Entry.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).exists():
    # Do something
```

Keep in mind that every time that you do `len(queryset)`, `item in queryset` or `list(queryset)` you decrees heavily the performance of Django. I already see cases where by avoiding this practices We improved dozens of seconds in an application.

Comment: `Entry.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).exists()`  will return `True` if at least one element of the list is inside the queryset

Answer (score 4):

in Django >= 4.0, `contains(obj)` is faster than the other methods.

**Method 1:**

```
if some_queryset.contains(obj):
    print('Object entry is in queryset')
```

**Method 1** above will be faster than the following **Method 2** which requires evaluating and iterating through the entire queryset:

**Method 2:**

```
if obj in some_queryset:
    print('Object entry is in queryset')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `in` operator:

```
entry_set = Entry.objects.all()
if an_entry in entry_set:
    # The element present.
```

Comment: Now in Django 4.0 you can use contains() method instead, if you ave already fetched the Queryset : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#contains

Answer (score -1):

You can just filter the queryset on the basis of a unique key present in the Entry model. Say, that key is id, your code would become:

```
is_present = Entry.objects.filter(id=e.id)
if is_present:
    print "Present"
else:
    print "Not Present"
```

Comment: using .exists() will prevent you from bringing in extra values if you can't filter off a unique key. It can also be used directly in the if statement, saving use of a variable. 
e.g. 'if Entry.objects.filter(id=e.id).exists():   ... do something here '